# Create a first order subgraph with edges only between seed nodes and their first interactors

Tags: r, graph, igraph, subgraph

I would like to generate a first-interactor subggraph from a group of seed nodes using a bigger graph as source. The source graph is huge with more than 300,000 edges, and my seed nodes are ~300. The subgraph (or multiple subgraphs) should contain the first interactors for each of the seed nodes.

I have applied the code in this post [Creating Subgraph using igraph in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23682113/creating-subgraph-using-igraph-in-r)
but it only gives me a big subgraph. I expect a big subgraph (continent) and another subgraphs with no connections to this bigger graph (islands).

Example code:

```
g <-erdos.renyi.game(50, 3/50)
seeds <- c(1,4,5,6,40,30)
sg <- decompose.graph(g)
neighverts <- unique(unlist(sapply(sg,FUN=function(s){if(any(V(s) %in% seeds)) V(s) else NULL})))
g1 <- induced.subgraph(graph=g,vids=neighverts)
```

The graph `g1` gives me the largest component from `decompose.graph`. This graph has my seed nodes and other nodes which are not first interactors for the seed nodes. What I am looking for is a subgraph, or a list of subgraphs, with the seed nodes and their first interactors. Maybe should I try with the `neighborhood` group functions?

Many thanks in advance

EDIT1:

Following Gabor suggestion I have used `neigborhood` function with `order=1`. However, I still don't get my expected result. Please find below a detailed example:

```
mat <- structure(list(X1 = c("5203820", "9985655", "5203820", "1795907","2190697", "5203820", "3233174", "1773848", "892104", "9976862","9987167", "9987134", "1211741", "1722252", "9986835", "9986879","9986835", "61145", "3442328", "5203820", "9987075", "3442328","1773848", "119371", "9986887", "2190697", "9987032", "9974927","9986835", "892104", "3744713", "9974927", "5118892", "9987134","9987134", "3442328", "2190697", "5203820", "9985655", "9987167","9990684", "3233174", "5203820", "9990684", "3744713", "9990684","9990684", "61145", "9990684", "3442328", "5378006", "9987035","9987035", "9987088", "3442328", "5118895"), X2 = c("61145","9987167","4928047", "9975931", "3744713", "3744713", "9975931","3820326", "9987100", "9987035", "9990670", "9990670", "9984628","3588994", "9986879", "9987059", "9987059", "9978463", "9986877","1795907", "9987142", "3588994", "1211741", "2111600", "9987124","1773848", "9987228", "9987100", "3442328", "3820326", "9983385","9978897", "9987019", "9987059", "5143742", "5143742", "9983385","9978463", "9987134", "9986887", "9990684", "9990684", "9990684","5373267", "9990684", "5389588", "5389374", "9990684", "5393513","9987088", "9987088", "9987035", "5118895", "9987088", "9987035","9987088")), .Names = c("X1", "X2"), row.names = c(NA, -56L), class = "data.frame")

g <- graph.data.frame(mat, directed=F)
seeds <- c('1722252', '9990670', '3442328', '5378006', '9990684', '9978463')
g1 <- induced.subgraph(g, vids = unlist(neighborhood(g, 1, nodes = seeds)))

plot(g1)
```

[image: image1].

The result shows an edge between node '5143742' and '9987134'. My expected result is only the seed nodes(seeds) and the edges between them and the first interactors, not including those edges between first interactors

Thanks again

Comment: Yes, use neighborhood, with `order = 1`.

Comment: Thanks @GaborCsardi, but could you help me with the new edit? Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get induce subgraph that contains only edges between seed vertices and their first interactors, you can use `subgraph.edges` as you indicated in the comment.

```
g1 <- subgraph.edges(g, unlist(get.adjedgelist(g)[seeds]) )
```

Comment: Thanks @ahmohamed but my expected result hasn't the edges between 5203820 and 61145, or the edge between 514372 y 9987134. I think I need to use `subgraph.edges` but not sure

Comment: I rewrote the answer as you explained.

Comment: Thanks @ahmohamed, that is exactly what was looking for. I was struggling how to get the edge ids, but from your answer it is really easy!!! I think the trick was `get.adjedgelist`

Comment: You are welcome. I edited the question title to better describe what you wanted.