# How to create a subgraph of a community using igraph

Tags: r, igraph, network-analysis

I have performed a community detection algorithm on my network and have a list of clusters as output.  I would like to do several things with these clusters but am struggling with how to manipulate them.  To start with I would like to create subgraphs by referencing eg Cluster 1.  Below is some of my code.

I have a dataframe that looks like this
**Person1   Person2 Volpc**
Person A    Person B    0.08
Person A    Lady A  0.08
Person A    Lady B  0.23
Person A    Lady C  0.38
Lady B  Mr CC   0.29
Lady B  Lady A  0.23
Lady B  Person B    0.87
Lady C  Lady A  0.87
Lady C  Lady B  1.01
Mr D    Mr CC   0.94

```
#First I created an adjacency matrix from by data set of links LinkSummary for which
#the weight is named Volpc

G <- graph.data.frame(LinkSummary,directed=FALSE);
A <- as_adjacency_matrix(G,type="both",names=TRUE,sparse=FALSE,attr="Volpc");


#build a graph

netw <- graph.adjacency(A,weighted=T, mode="undirected")

#remove loops
netw <- simplify(netw)

#I used the walktrap algorithm to find communities
wt<- walktrap.community(netw, steps=6,modularity=TRUE,weights = E(G)$Volpc)
```

I have been experimenting with the number of clusters to find the best solution.
 Without this option a lot of the nodes were placed in one massive cluster.  This helped to break them up.

```
#increase number clusters
wt2 <- cut_at(wt, no=300)
```

I put the results into a table and outputted them to excel and produced something that looked like this

```
memtwt <- table(names, wt2 )
write.table(memtwt, file="clipboard-16384", sep="\t", row.names=TRUE) increase buffer
```

**Node**   1    2   3   4
**Person A**    1   0   0   0
**Lady A**  0   1   0   0
**Lady B**  1   0   0   0
**Lady C**  0   0   0   1
**Mr D**    0   0   1   0
**Person B**    0   0   1   0
**Mr CC**   1   0   0   0

Unfortunately it looks like a lot of my clusters are based on ties with one node.
To view the interactions I created a subnetwork 
(using code from here [Creating Subgraph using igraph in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23682113/creating-subgraph-using-igraph-in-r))

```
# we want a sub-network containing the following nodes:
subv <- c('Person A','Lady B','Mr CC')


# create a sub-network composed by ONLY the nodes in subv and the edges 
# between them
g2 <- induced.subgraph(graph=netw,vids=subv)

plot(g2,  vertex.size=3, edge.color="black",edge.width=E(g2)$weight/10)
```

What I would like is to be able to assign each cluster to a variable so that I can
view the subnetworks each time I have different results without typing out a list of names, something like this...

```
subv <- wt2(1)
g3 <- induced.subgraph(graph=netw,vids=subv)
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: You need to provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Include some sample data and the desired output for the that input. That will make it easier to help you.